# smart contract with brownie gives VirtualMachineError

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, brownie

I encontered a problem when I test my project, any help would be greatly appreciated.
All my code can be found in here: https://github.com/Karlus44/smartcontract-lottery
When I type the command brownie test
my script tests/test_lottery_unit.py is exectuted, and my different tests are submitted.
Here some quotes of my logout:

```
Brownie v1.18.1 - Python development framework for Ethereum
```

================================== test session starts ===================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.11.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/karlus/Documents/NFT-Contract/smartcontract-lottery
plugins: eth-brownie-1.18.1, forked-1.4.0, web3-5.27.0, hypothesis-6.27.3, xdist-1.34.0
collected 4 items

Launching 'ganache-cli --accounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --gasLimit 12000000 --mnemonic br
ownie --port 8545'...

tests/test_lottery_unit.py ...F                                                    [100%]

======================================== FAILURES ========================================
__________________________________ test_can_end_lottery __________________________________

```
def test_can_end_lottery():
    # Arrange
    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        pytest.skip()
    lottery = deploy_lottery()
    account = get_account()
    lottery.startLottery({"from": account})
    lottery.enter({"from": account, "value":lottery.getEntranceFee()})
    fund_with_link(lottery)
    print(f"endlottery: {lottery.endLottery}")
```

> ```
>   transaction = lottery.endLottery({"from": account})
> ```

E       brownie.exceptions.VirtualMachineError: revert
E       Trace step -1, program counter 2469:
E         File "/home/karlus/.brownie/packages/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contract
s@1.1.1/contracts/src/v0.6/VRFConsumerBase.sol", line 161, in VRFConsumerBase.requestRando
mness:
E           function requestRandomness(bytes32 _keyHash, uint256 _fee)
E             internal returns (bytes32 requestId)
E           {
E             LINK.transferAndCall(vrfCoordinator, _fee, abi.encode(_keyHash, USER_SEED_PL
ACEHOLDER));
E             // This is the seed passed to VRFCoordinator. The oracle will mix this with
E             // the hash of the block containing this request to obtain the seed/input
E             // which is finally passed to the VRF cryptographic machinery.

tests/test_lottery_unit.py:58: VirtualMachineError

tests/test_lottery_unit.py:58: VirtualMachineError
---------------------------------- Captured stdout call ----------------------------------
0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871
Deployed lottery!
Fund contract!
endlottery: <ContractTx 'endLottery()'>
Transaction sent: 0x59a0a2fdf727591891380c80c0fd90329c8a11b527e24c07d33652b26dfd32c7
================================ short test summary info =================================
FAILED tests/test_lottery_unit.py::test_can_end_lottery - brownie.exceptions.VirtualMac...
============================== 1 failed, 3 passed in 7.97s ===============================
Terminating local RPC client...

Linter
Severity Provider Description Line

So as you can see, my 3 first tests are correctly functionning, but my function fulfillRandomness doesn't seem to be called, and I can't figure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `fund_with_link` function. Check the amount that you have mentioned. It must be `amount = 0.1 * 10**18`.

As mentioned here, https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf-contracts/v1/ , the fee for, say, Rinkeby test network is `0.1 LINK`.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. In my ’fund_with_link’ function I wrote

 def fund_with_link(contract_address, account=None, link_token=None, amount=100000000000000000): # 0.1 Link

so it seems the right amount is set.

Comment: Hello ! So you were right after all !
I believed I was giving the amount in the line of code I mentionned, but actually my program was using data from my brownie-config.yaml.
Well thank you very much !

Comment: Glad that I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're having a virtual machine check with your ganache port and IP in the settings of your Ethereum VM. If you're running `brownie-compile` and the code is working, then that's the issue.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.
I'm not comfortable with those port settings.
I am using ’brownie-compile’, with 3 different networks and I get an error with all three.
The first is my development network:
’Development
  ├─Ganache-CLI
  │ ├─id: development
  │ ├─cmd: ganache-cli
  │ └─host: http://127.0.0.1
  │   ├─accounts: 10
  │   ├─evm_version: istanbul
  │   ├─gas_limit: 12000000
  │   ├─mnemonic: brownie
  │   └─port: 8545’
I also the truffle suite with ’ganache-local’:
’ganache-local
    ├─id: ganache-local
    ├─chainid: 1337
    └─host: http://127.0.0.1:8545’

Comment: and rinkeby:
├─Rinkeby (Infura)
  │ ├─id: rinkeby
  │ ├─chainid: 4
  │ ├─explorer: https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io/api
  │ ├─host: https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't manage to edit this correctly. My two test network use the 8545 port, wich I believe is correct, but maybe you can see more easily than me any mistake I've left.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the fee you have entered in brownie-config.yaml is 0.1 LINK. This should solve the problem.